# What is the impact of a meta tag with content="noindex,nofollow"

Tags: html, indexing, meta-tags

One of my clients is discussing a partnership. The potential partner is asking us to insert the following meta tag in the head-section of our site to "prevent their competitors from indexing the site":

`<meta property="partnername:index" content="noindex,nofollow"/>`

I really can't see what this tag does and if there is a risk that it prevents standard search engine crawlers (Google, Bing, ...) from indexing the pages.

To be clear: if there was a name attribute with value "robots", this would have been the usual way to tell search engines not to index and not to follow links on the page, but here it is different: no name attribute but a property attribute with the partner's name followed by ":index"

Answer (score 3):

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
```

> The robots meta tag in the above example instructs search engines not
> to show the page in search results. The value of the name attribute (
> robots) specifies that the directive applies to all crawlers. To
> address a specific crawler, replace the robots value of the name
> attribute with the name of the crawler that you are addressing.
> Specific crawlers are also known as user agents (a crawler uses its
> user agent to request a page.) Google's standard web crawler has the
> user agent name Googlebot.

Whereas `nofollow` is defined like this:

> Do not follow the links on this page. If you don't specify this
> directive, Google may use the links on the page to discover those
> linked pages.

Source: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/robots_meta_tag

So for your example, the potential partner wants to blacklist the crawlers of its competitors. Whether that's worth it or not, is up to you.

Comment: I know that, but in this case there is no name attribute with "robots" as value, which is why I ask the question

Comment: I've just checked [Yandex](https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/controlling-robot/html.html), [Bing](https://www.bing.com/webmasters/help/which-robots-metatags-does-bing-support-5198d240) and  [Baidu](https://www.baidu.com/search/robots_english.html) - neither of these list support for the property tag. Even if, its value would have to match either `robots` or the name of the robot the company is using to have any effect.

Comment: So, which is the crawler that will be blacklisted? The one appearing as the value of the property attribute ("partnername:index")? The thing is that this is the the potential partner! So they're shooting themselves in the leg, or what?

Comment: I have a possible explanation to what they may WANT to achieve: Since the partner's site will have a link to my client's site they may want any crawler crawling THEIR site to stop and not crawl my client's site. This is pure speculation and I don't know if that would be achieved with the tag.

Comment: Exactly, the value of the property attribute will define for whom `noindex` and `nofollow` applies. The intention of this tag is clear, they want someone not to list and index your customer's page, which, without knowing anything about the whole thing, sounds a bit weird to me.

Answer (score 1):

**nofollow** tag tells search engine spiders to ignore the link relationship,
**noindex** tag requests the robot to not index the page.

[Check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta/name)

Comment: With a name attribute and value "robots" yes, I know, but in this case there is no name attribute but a property attribute with a value which seems strange to me

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow,noarchive" />
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.